# What is the energy density of the inflaton field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, potential-energy, units, cosmological-inflation

I am trying to compare the theoretically calculated vacuum energy density according to quantum field theory with the energy density of the inflaton field, in joules per cubic meter (or Pascal). I found that the first is about $10^{113}$ joules per cubic meter according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_energy), and that the second has an energy scale of about 10$^{16}$ GeV according to [this paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1420368/files/207.pdf) (p. 215). However, I am unsure about how to convert these two different units. I also cannot find the energy density of the inflaton field in joules per cubic meter (maybe because the universe is much smaller than a cubic meter during inflation?).

I read that the energy density of the inflaton field is more or less constant while inflation is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy density of inflation is dominated by its potential $V$, i.e. $\rho\simeq V$. Your linked paper defined inflation's energy scale to be $V^{1/4}\simeq 10^{16}~\mathrm{GeV}$, which implies that the associated energy density is

$$\rho = (10^{16}~\mathrm{GeV})^4 = 10^{64}~\mathrm{GeV}^4$$

Note that we don't really know the energy scale of inflation, but $10^{16}$ GeV is a typical value for inflation models. It [can't be much higher than that](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5258).

How does this relate to conventional units like $\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m}^3$? Just set $\hbar=c=1$, so that $1~\mathrm{GeV}\simeq 5.0677\times 10^{15}~\mathrm{m}^{-1}$. Meanwhile $1~\mathrm{GeV}\simeq 1.6022\times 10^{-10}~\mathrm{J}$, so $\mathrm{GeV}^4\simeq 2.085\times 10^{37}~\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m}^3$, and hence

$$\rho \simeq 2\times 10^{101}~\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m}^3.$$

---

Of course, that's a very roundabout way to compare things. The Wikipedia value for the vacuum energy, $10^{113}~\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m}^3$, is just $m_\mathrm{p}^4$, where $m_\mathrm{p}\simeq 1.22\times 10^{19}~\mathrm{GeV}$ is the Planck mass. So you are really just comparing the $(10^{19}~\mathrm{GeV})^4$ vacuum energy density to the $(10^{16}~\mathrm{GeV})^4$ inflation energy density.

Comment: While the ultimate answer in $J/m^3$ is correct, 1 GeV is approx $1.6022 \times 10^{-10} J$

Comment: @MrAnderson Thanks! Seems I carelessly wrote down the conversion for eV instead.