# Could cosmic inflation restart?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

Is it possible for a region of space in our universe to reenter an inflationary state? For example, if a particle accelerator collision of sufficiently high energy recreated conditions under which the early universe experienced inflation, would that patch of space inflate?

An argument in favor of it restarting is the notion in particle physics that all processes that are not forbidden  by the laws of nature
do actually do occur, combined with the fact that the microscopic laws of physics are reversible. So if the universe in an inflationary state could transition to a non-inflationary state of high energy density during the Big Bang, then given the right conditions it seems that the reverse process should be possible.

But intuitively it is hard to imagine inflation restarting. In my understanding, inflation creates space exponentially, and the created space has enormous energy density. It seems very counterintuitive that a local process could trigger something so dramatic.

Comment: Cosmic rays have been detected far, far more energetic than the biggest particle accelerator collision. If they can't do it, we can't.

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/733411/what-is-the-energy-density-of-the-inflaton-field) tells you the energy density you need to achieve.

Comment: In addition I would take a step back and question whether inflation is really the answer to the early universe. Inflation, right now, is at best a hypothesis.

Comment: This is a hypothetical question. If we could collide particles (or larger objects) at sufficiently high energies... Also since the question is about inflation, take it to mean "supposing there was an inflationary period at the beginning of the universe..." I know there are many different models of inflation, but that is also fine. It would be interesting to know if different models gave different answers to this question.

Comment: If the cosmic bank starts printing more money, then inflation would be a concern for the cosmic economy...